# Wordpress GitHub Workflow

Tags: github

I currently have a WordPress GitHub workflow that is the following:

- Development is done locally
- -> committed to the GitHub repository
- -> is pushed to the dev WP site/admin panel
- -> QA'd
- -> merged with the Production Github branch to push live to the Prod WP site/admin panel.

The client would like to be able to create changes in the WP admin panel (adding new plugins) then commit those to the rest of the GitHub repository so that when I commit changes his work isn't overwritten.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Recommendations are off topic here, recommendation questions get closed as off topic, can you remove/edit out that part of your question?

Comment: Adding plugins is just adding files - which can easily be done on GitHub, yes - and enabling them in the database. Is the database versioned here somehow? If not, then just adding the files should be enough